# PHP Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class not found

Tags: php, orm, doctrine

I am trying to go trough tutorial of doctrine here is official [website](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/tutorials/getting-started.html). And I got an error in Starting with the Product Entity part.

This is what I write to terminal: `$ php create_product.php ORM`

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'product' not found in /home/vaclav/Server/vssk/VSSK/project/create_product.php:8
Stack trace: #0 {main}
  thrown in /home/vaclav/Server/vssk/VSSK/project/create_product.php on line 8
```

Comment: Well, what's on line 8 of that file?

Comment: My bad I frgot to write It. $product = new Product();

Comment: So it seems that in the create_product.php file then, you haven't loaded the `product()` class. 

It looks like the project uses Composer to load the classes. Are you sure you have that configured correctly. That's where you should start looking.

Comment: And where Product class is defined?

Comment: `<?php
// src/Product.php

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity @ORM\Table(name="products")
 **/
class product
{
    /** @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer") @ORM\GeneratedValue **/
    protected $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string") **/
    protected $name;


    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->name;
    }

    public function setName($name)
    {
        $this->name = $name;
    }
}
`

Comment: Obviously I have problem load class product from file Product.php. But I don't know ho to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved with adding:

```
require 'path_to_your_class/Product.php';
```

to `create_product.php`.

Or you need to configure [PHP autoload](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.autoload.php)